# Rails pagination: How to get the first element of the second page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I'm using pagination in Rails with will_paginate. I have a table with 99 items loaded. When I try to get the first element of the second page using the following command:

```
Item.paginate(page: 2).first
```

Rails returns:

```
#<Item id: 2, ...>
```

However, the correct answer should be:

```
#<Item id: 32, ...>
```

Interestingly, indexing the first element in the resulting array without using the "first" method gives the right answer, so:

```
Item.paginate(page: 2)[0]
```

returns:

```
#<Item id: 32, ...>
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

[There appears to be a bug](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/223) in will_paginate and the .first method. I suspect you can work around it by doing:

```
Item.paginate(page: 2).all.first
```

This works similarly to your work around.

Comment: I would suggest that you voice in on that bug thread. The more people affected by it the more likely it is to get fixed.

Comment: I'll do it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: They closed the issue overriding AR's first() method.

Comment: Awesome! Looks like they released a new version, too.